# Adding multiple filenames to listBox, but without extensions? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, openfiledialog, file-extension

I'm making a program that adds executable files to a listBox in C#.

I'm trying to add the items to the listBox without the .exe extension.  This is the code I had previously:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(openFiles.SafeFileNames.Replace(".exe",""));
```

It worked fine, but it doesn't have support for multiple files.  When the code runs after selecting multiple items rather than one, it adds the item "System.String[]" (Which isn't good! D:)

Can I get some help?  I'll try to explain this a little better, I haven't had much sleep so I might be rambling a bit -

I want to add multiple files to my listBox at the same time, with my openFileDialog that is set to multiSelect = true, but excluding the file extensions (.exe) from being entered into the listBox along with the individual items.

If this can't be done easily, I'll just switch back to single-select.

Comment: Are you sure you won't have a filename like `my.executor.exe`? Because your code would change that into `mycutor`, instead of `my.executor`.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)` method.

EDIT:

```
foreach (string FileName in openFiles.SafeFileNames)
  {
    listBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do a loop, removing the ".exe" from each file name in the returned array:

```
foreach (string fileName in openFiles.SafeFileNames)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(fileName.Replace(".exe",""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileInfo class. It has name with and without extensions, as well as with the entire directory name and filename as well.  [MSDN FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)